# Software like Twitter Bootstrap for Android

Tags: android, library

Is there a popular open source project that is similar to Twitter Bootstrap for Android development? I am mainly looking for something would have better UI components than what Android has.

Comment: I don't post this as an answer, but you might want to think about it. I guess you are thinking of Java code? I quit that and moved to browser based, so my stuff also works on Ios, Windows, Linux, Mac, Raspberry Pi ... anything that has a browser. I am using AngularJS (by Google, so great s/w, with great support) The Bootstrap is at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  If you need access to the Adnroid's devices, such as camera, GPS, etc, use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @Mawg Yeah - I'm looking solely for a native (Java) library that would have UI components and styles, not for a web app.

Comment: kk. np. I guess that GINYF. But, why not S.O with an Android tag? Otoh, you might be surprised at what can :-) be achieved with non-JS, non-Android native. I know that I was